# How the output is possible in the following?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
'#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{ 
    short arr[3][2]={3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18}; 
    printf("%d  %d", *(arr + 1)[1], **(arr + 2)); 
}'
```

The output of the program is 15,15?

Comment: Post text as text, not images! And we are not a "do my homework" service.

Comment: Read [ask] and the FAQ. Learn how to copy&paste text on your platform. That's basic computer-operation knowledge.

Comment: Please edit the question. Not next time. That is not a suggestion, but site-rules. Please follow them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the image given, It has a `3*2` matrix i.e 3 rows and two 2 rows.

`*(arr+1)[1]` can be interpreted like this:

`arr+1`  gives the address of 2nd row 1st element.

`(arr+1)[1]` gives the address of 3rd row 1st element.

`*(arr+1)[1]` gives the value present at this address

Following is the example:

```
void main(){
  short arr[3][2]={3,6,9,12,15,18};
  printf("%d %d %d %d", (arr ),(arr+1),(arr+1)[1],(arr +2));
}
```

Output:

```
-977229152 -977229148 -977229144 -977229144
```

Comment: I think above edited answer would clarify your doubt

Comment: Thank you for your explanation,i thought  * ( arr +  1)[1]  is equivalent to a[1][1],thats why i am confused so according to ur explanation its equals to a[2][0].

Comment: Okay, To be more clear *(*(arr+1)[1]) gives arr[1][1]. Because firstly, *(arr+1) is evaluated which holds arr[1][0]. Later it move to the next address location . which is arr[1][1].

Comment: In *(arr+1)[1] , the compiler treats it at once. i.e arr+1+1 which is arr[2][0].

Comment: *Output is the value at the location of a[i][j].*: No.

Comment: @haccks I know it is not the answer. That's why i have edited the post and mentioned about the difference in the comment section above. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As per the operator precedence rule `*(a+i)[j]` will be parsed as `*((a + i)[j])` which is ultimately equivalent to `*( *(a + i + j) )`. So for `i = 1` and `j = 1` it will be `*( *(a + 1 + 1) ) = *( *( a + 2) + 0) = a[2][0]`

Comment: But,assume i=1,j=1 ,the output is not a[1][1] its a[2][0]

Comment: @SwarajSomala; Edited my answer.